# PHP: Maximum number of form (FILE) fields

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I want to upload 50 files at the same time (well, a clients wants this 'amazing feature'). However, PHP only processes the first 20 form fields; after that, they just do not exist for PHP.

I've had this problem before but did not document properly how to solve it. I believe it's a PHP setting, but I can not find it.

Comment: Suggest you look at some form of imitated AJAX upload (yes everyone, I know you can't upload files with ajax, but you can do some neat things with iframes - look at the file manager in cPanel). This gives you the advantage of being able to upload the earlier files while they are still selecting the later ones, and the whole process will take longer and the risk of the server connection timing out is reduced...

Comment: @DaveRandom thanks for the suggestion, and this is a nice fix, but in this case we needed a fast and simple solution, and those AJAX script will take some more time to set up than just `echo` the same form field 50 times...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In php.ini, change `max_file_uploads = 20` to whatever value you need.

[Common Pitfalls for file upload in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need `max_file_uploads` setting in your php.ini file. Also do check the `upload_max_filesize` and `pos_max_size` settings, to be safe :)